# Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am trying to verify a jwt using jsonwebtoken. When I am using:

```
jwt.verify(jwt, publicKey)
```

I am getting a :

> JsonWebTokenError {name: "JsonWebTokenError", message: "invalid
>   algorithm", stack: "JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm }

When I am using:

```
jwt.verify(jwt, publicKey, { algorithms: 'RS256'})
```

I am getting:

> Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Any ideas? Is there an alternative to verify a jwt?

**Update**

The problem lies on the RS256 selection probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing an options object with both audience and issuer attributes .

```
let options = {
    clockTolerance: 60*24*10, 
    audience: "account",
    issuer: "https://login.someorganization/auth"
};

jwt.verify(jwt, publicKey, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sample above, you are referencing the jwt instance in your verify function

Use the link [npm-jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

You will have to verify a token, not the jwt instance
Example

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'private_key');
```

Where 'private_key' is the exact key used for hashing